# iPhone dev - Where is the navigation controller in a navigation-based app template?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I'm confused about the Navigation-based app template. Does it not provide you with a UINavigationController? Because RootViewController is a UITableViewController, so what do I use as the navigation controller? (where do I actually do the pushing?) Do I have to make my own navigationController? Where should I make it? And why would something called a Navigation-based app not provide you with a navigation controller? I'm very confused. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

It's in the MainWindow.xib
On code, it will be connected to the IBOutlet in your AppDelegate.
In applicationDidFinishLaunching this will be added and made as the key window.

Answer (score 0):

Navigation controller is added on mainWindow.xib and connected through an IBOutlet in appDelegate class. in applicationDidFinishLaunching method navigation controller'v view is added to window. Navigation controller has one view controller which is assigned class named rootViewcontroller and assigned a nib named rootviewcontroller. you can see by opening and inspectind mainwindow.xib.

Comment: Thanks. So if I want to access the navigationcontroller to push new tableviewcontrollers onto its stack, I have to do it within myProjAppDelegate.m? Or can (should?) I access it outside of myProjAppDelegate.m?

Comment: @Tim Not necessarily. You can access the navigation controller through the RootViewController using the `navigationController` property of [UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) because it is in the navigation controller's stack. For example, in the RootViewController class you could do: `[self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES];`